# Lua: return content of "{foo}{bar}"

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

for a string like `"{foo}{bar}"` is there an easy

```
str = "{foo}{bar}"
first, second = str:gmatch(...)...
```

should give `first="foo"` and `second="bar"`

The problem is that `foo` itself can have some more parentheses, eg:

```
str = "{foo {baz}{bar}"
```

so that `first = "foo {baz"` The 
`bar` part has only alphanumerical characters, no parentheses

Comment: What about `first, second = str:match('({[^}]*})%s*({[^}]*})')`?

Comment: For `{foo}{bar}` I'll get `first="{foo}"` and `second="{bar}"`, but it should be  `first="foo"` and `second="bar"`,  without the _outer_ braces

Comment: I moved the capturing parentheses wrongly: `first, second = str:match('{([^}]*)}%s*{([^}]*)}')`. See https://ideone.com/aFroK5

Comment: yes, that's fine :-). Please give it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
first, second = str:match('{([^}]*)}%s*{([^}]*)}')
```

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/aFroK5)

The `str.match` function will find and return the first match and since there are two capturing groups there will be two values returned upon a valid match.

The pattern means:

- `{` - a `{` char
- `([^}]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `}`
- `}` - a `}` char
- `%s*` - 0+ whitespaces (not necessary, but a bonus)
- `{([^}]*)}` - same as above, just there is a Group 2 defined here.

Comment: In this case I'll get `nil`: `str = "{Während|see{Was\\_auch\\_immmer}}{17}"`. But it should return `Während|see{Was\\_auch\\_immmer}` and `17`. I suppose the parentheses in the left part are the problem.

Comment: @Herbert Probably, I am overthinking it here. If you only expect two values `{..}` and then the last `{}`, use a mere `str:match('{(.*)}%s*{(.*)}')`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/8HE0P9)